# geany syntax highlighting in double quotes

Tags: perl, geany

I have a perl script containing following line as example:

```
print "my newvar = $newvar";
```

VIM syntax highlighting understands that $var in double quotes is interpolated variable, and marks it in different color, however in Geany editor any text and variable inside double quotes considered as comment text. Is it possible to configure it the same way as in vim?

Comment: There's an open [feature request](http://sourceforge.net/p/geany-plugins/feature-requests/85/) dated from 2011 for highlighting interpolated strings. From [this feature request](http://sourceforge.net/p/scintilla/feature-requests/815/) at Scintilla it seems that it hasn't been implemented yet. What confuses me, is that Notepad++ on Windows which is also based on Scintilla, doesn't have this issue.

Comment: No idea about Scintilla, but I know a lot of editors have script-ish highlighting mechanisms and notepad++ may well be implementing the desired feature downstream. If that is the case you *might* be able to examine an installation of notepad++ and determine what changes might be necessary to make Geany do the same.

Comment: You should add some more content to the freature tracker as stackoverflow is not the right place

Comment: interestng but in my notepad++ with perl filetype it also does not highlight $var inside double quotes...

Comment: UPDATE: this problem fixed in the latest geany version 1.23.1

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know the problem source was Perl Lexer in Scintilla.

So in that old lexer if the style context is in *default* state and double quotation mark is matched then style context will be set to *string* state, on the other hand if the style is in *string* state double quotation mark is matched then style *context* will be set to back default state. There was no any other style context switches between double quotations marks.

For giving a code segment example:

```
for (; scCTX . More () ; scCTX . Forward ()) {
    switch ( scCTX . state ) {
    case SCE_SPARKS_DEFAULT :
       if ( scCTX . Match ( '\"' )) {
            scCTX . SetState ( SCE_SPARKS_STRING );
            break ;
         };
        *
        *
        *
    case SCE_SPARKS_STRING :
        if ( scCTX . Match ('\"')) {
            scCTX . ForwardSetState ( SCE_SPARKS_DEFAULT );
        };
        break ;
       *
       *
```

Solution could be modifying or adding new lexer in that time. But since the update mentioned in comment there is no need for that now .